# Can't compile QT 5.5.1 on Amazon Centos: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick

Tags: linux, qt, amazon-ec2

I am trying to compile QT 5.5.1 on Amazon AMI 2015.09, which looks la lot like Centos 6.5.

I keep getting this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick
```

However, there is no `quick` module that I can find, and no obvious way to enable to disable it from looking at the `./configure` script.

My procedure:

1. I downloaded `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1.tar.gz`
2. I unpacked it.
3. I ran ./configure
4. Confirmed that I want the opensource license and agreed to the LGPL.
5. Ran `gmake -j4` (but I get the same behavior with `gmake`.

Interestingly, `make distclean` gives me this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick-private
```

Here are all of the errors sent to STDERR:

```
Checking for openal... Checking for bluez... no
Checking for bluez_le... no
Checking for btapi10_2_1... no
/home/ec2-user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro:28: Variable GST_VERSION is not defined.
Checking for resourcepolicy... no
Checking for gpu_vivante... no
Checking for libbb2... no
no
Project MESSAGE: Unsupported Bluetooth platform, will not build a working QtBluetooth library.
Project MESSAGE: Either no Qt D-Bus found or no BlueZ headers.
qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent_p.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
qbluetoothservicediscoveryagent_p.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
qbluetoothserver_p.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
qbluetoothlocaldevice_p.h:0: Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.
Checking for assimp... no
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick
gmake[4]: *** [sub-textureandlight-make_first] Error 3
gmake[3]: *** [sub-canvas3d-make_first] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [sub-canvas3d-make_first] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [sub-examples-make_first] Error 2
gmake: *** [module-qtcanvas3d-make_first] Error 2
gmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

At another poster's suggestion I tried `./configure -skip qtquick` but that didn't work:

```
$ ./configure -skip qtquick
+ cd qtbase
+ /home/ec2-user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/configure -top-level -skip qtquick
Attempting to skip non-existent module qtquick.
$
```

Comment: Check the configure output if it succeeds and every necessary is found, especially OpenGL-related dependencies. the subfolder of QtQuick is qtdeclarative/, it should be in your 5.5.1 tarball.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to find the list of dependencies.?

Comment: configure should print its results.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, unfortunately configure does not include the word "quick" in its output.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I think will solve your problems:

1. You have use  `make *confclean*'  instead of making distclean for deleting the previous configuration.
2. Configure in verbose mode — more information will be provided, sorry, I don't remember exact flag, if I'm not mistaken, it's *-v*.
3. If you don't need quick, add -*skip qtquick* to the configure.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and let you know.  The "-skip qtquick" isn't documented in the usage of the configuration program. Where did you find that option?

Comment: Doesn't work: `Attempting to skip non-existent module qtquick.`

Comment: Try -skip quick instead of -skip qtquick. And add also -skip declarative and -skip qml. Try different combinations. Source: http://doc.qt.io/qbs/qt-modules.html

Comment: Alas, when I tried that, I got another error: `QmlDebugServerThread::run(): error: undefined reference to 'QTcpServerConnection::QTcpServerConnection()'
`

Comment: Exactly what configuration options did you use?
Have you tried: 
1. _-skip quick_
2. _-skip quick -skip declarative_
3.  _-skip quick -skip declarative -skip qml_
4. _-skip declarative_ ?

Comment: I did a`./configure -skip quick -skip qml`. That seemed to change the settings. But I still need to do a `./configure` to get configure to run. I also provided `-static` and `-shared` and `-open-source`

Comment: Once again, **try** _-skip declarative_.